# Setting INDEX in mysql for better search

Tags: mysql, indexing

Lets say i have this sample table:

```
CREATE  TABLE `users` (
   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   `name` VARCHAR(512) NULL ,
   `lastname` VARCHAR(512) NULL ,
   `country` VARCHAR(256) NULL ,
   `tags` VARCHAR(512) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

Basically the "tags" column is just key words that are set for the user

Now what i want to do is be able to search for a user **based on the name and tags**
To have fast search, i would had to create an index on **"name"** and **"tags"**

So to create index should i do:

```
ALTER TABLE `vidhucr1_serverlist`.`new_table` 
ADD INDEX `INDEX` (`name` ASC, `tags` ASC) ;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE `vidhucr1_serverlist`.`new_table` 
ADD INDEX `INDEX1` (`name` ASC) 
, ADD INDEX `INDEX2` (`tags` ASC) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a single index (`name, tags`) should be better as long as your query filters `names` and `tags`. If your query should omit `tags`, the index would be useless (last statement under example 1). Also, I hope that you do not have multiple "tags" in the `tags` field.

**Example 1 - Composite Index**

Indexes: `INDEX (name, tags)`

Index would be used for `SELECT ... WHERE name = '...' AND tags = '...'` *or* `SELECT ... WHERE tags = '...' AND name = '...'`

```
| ID | SELECT_TYPE | TABLE | TYPE | POSSIBLE_KEYS |   KEY | KEY_LEN |         REF | ROWS |       EXTRA |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |      SIMPLE | users |  ref |         INDEX | INDEX |    1536 | const,const |    1 | Using where |
```

Index would be used for `SELECT ... WHERE name = '...'`

```
| ID | SELECT_TYPE | TABLE | TYPE | POSSIBLE_KEYS |   KEY | KEY_LEN |   REF | ROWS |       EXTRA |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |      SIMPLE | users |  ref |         INDEX | INDEX |     768 | const |    1 | Using where |
```

**No** index used for `SELECT ... WHERE tags = '...'`

```
| ID | SELECT_TYPE | TABLE | TYPE | POSSIBLE_KEYS |    KEY | KEY_LEN |    REF | ROWS |       EXTRA |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |      SIMPLE | users |  ALL |        (null) | (null) |  (null) | (null) |    1 | Using where |
```

**Example 2 - Two Single Indexes**

Indexes: `INDEX1 (name)`, `INDEX2 (tags)`

Both indexes used for `SELECT ... WHERE name = '...' AND tags = '...'`

```
| ID | SELECT_TYPE | TABLE | TYPE | POSSIBLE_KEYS |    KEY | KEY_LEN |   REF | ROWS |       EXTRA |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |      SIMPLE | users |  ref | INDEX1,INDEX2 | INDEX1 |     768 | const |    1 | Using where |
```

`INDEX1` used for `SELECT ... WHERE tags = '...'`

```
| ID | SELECT_TYPE | TABLE | TYPE | POSSIBLE_KEYS |    KEY | KEY_LEN |   REF | ROWS |       EXTRA |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |      SIMPLE | users |  ref |        INDEX1 | INDEX1 |     768 | const |    1 | Using where |
```

`INDEX2` used for `SELECT ... WHERE name = '...'`

```
| ID | SELECT_TYPE | TABLE | TYPE | POSSIBLE_KEYS |    KEY | KEY_LEN |   REF | ROWS |       EXTRA |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |      SIMPLE | users |  ref |        INDEX2 | INDEX2 |     768 | const |    1 | Using where |
```

Comment: So if i do  `idx(name, tag)`
When querying i HAVE to use the name and tag fields? or would be useless if i just used one of them?

Comment: The index will be used whenever the query searches on a prefix of the index. So it will be used when you search for `name` alone or both `name` and `tag`. But if you just search for `tag`, the index will not be used.

Comment: i see, but why is that? y cant u use a WHERE with only tags?

Comment: Indexes work left to right. If you have a composite index (`name, tags`), the optimizer will only scan the first column (`name`) if your filter is only using `tags`.

Comment: what if i wanted to search using tag only? or name only? would i have to do `ADD INDEX 'INDEX1' ('name' ASC), ADD INDEX 'INDEX2' ('tags' ASC)`

Comment: @VidhuShresthBhatnagar See my update and the last statement under example 1.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it would be the first definition that creates an index of both name and tags together.

Secondly, I doubt if this would improve the searches as tags seems to be containing multiple values with some separator/delimiter and if it is normalized into a separate table `user_tags` with a one-to-many relationship between `users` and `user_tags`, then creating index on the `(user_id, tag)` columns would help. Then the index in `users` table would be simply on the `name` column.

Comment: That's a good point @Vokdor. I must change it. Thanks for pointing that out